# Add Kerberos ticket to SOAP header (Client) & read Kerberos ticket from SOAP header (server)

Tags: java, soap, kerberos, jaas

I have been reading about Kerberos and JAAS and GSS-API.  I now understand the basics, but I am struggling to translate that into actual code.  For now, I would like to perform two basic operations:

1. Get the Kerberos ticket and add it to the SOAP header on the client side before I call a Java web service running on WAS 8.
2. Read the SOAP header in the Java web service and pull out the Kerberos ticket.

I would appreciate any help you could provide.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please post the code you have tried

Comment: I haven't tried any code.  That's why I posted the question.  I don't really know where to begin.